# Unable to import FirefoxOptions in Selenium Java

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to import Firefox on my project, but it's not importing at all, even though I have downgraded selenium version as well. I am using following selenium maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Whenever I am trying to import `FireFoxOptions`. It is showing red colour text, I need to know, if I am making any mistake.

Comment: youre using intelij IDE?

Comment: Try running `mvn package` to make sure you downloaded the dependency and you should provide code how are you importing the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) maven dependency is perfect.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### This usecase

Instead of importing `FireFoxOptions` you should have imported *`FirefoxOptions`*. A demonstration:

- Code block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

  public class genericTestFirefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
  }
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

First: Can you work with the webdrivemanager ? It will help you in your configuration of selenium with firefox.

Second: To use Firefox option (eg: maximize your Window) use this exemple:

```
// Create an instance of FirefoxOptions
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

// Maximize the Firefox window
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

// Create an instance of Firefox with the options applied
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I hope it helps you !